# How would you fetch an ID of a person using their username on PHP using a database?

Tags: php

We have been set an exercise in which we have been given 1000 names on a database and have integrated that into phpMyAdmin. Our exercise is to find the ID number of a person after being given a specific username which is a series of numbers.

Comment: provide some code you have tried

Comment: What have you tried so far?  We aren't going to do your homework for you but if you post code you've tried you'll get help debugging it.

Comment: please add some code which you have tried so far @george

Comment: Try using https://secure.php.net/manual/ to learn php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $username = 'username'; //change this to the username you want to lookup
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    # If one or more rows were returned...
    if ( count($result) ) {
        foreach($result as $row) {
            print_r($row);
        }
     } else {
        echo "No rows returned.";
     }
   }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
      echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

This is an example when using PDO which is better at prevention against SQL injecttion by using prepared statements. There are plenty of tutuorials online on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! Apologies that I didn't present any code, a moment of stupidity on my half

Answer (score -1):

Thats quite simple, since you are new to php and Stack Overflow, I understand that you have not read how to post question, Please do some minimal research and then post it on SO if you are not able to find the answer, There are several tutorials for this on web, anyways. here you go.

```
  <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, name FROM users WHERE username='username'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "id: " . $row['id']. " - Nme: " . $row['name']. " " . $row['username']. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Learn php the easy way at http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp and it has the SQL part too.